# Can't create a menu

Tags: java, android, menu

I'm new to android trying to create a popup menu, but my app is crashing when I'm calling `createMenu()` in my activity which is extending to `AppCompatActivity` can anybody help me about the issue?

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    public void createMenu() {
        MenuBuilder menuBuilder = new MenuBuilder(this);
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, menuBuilder);
        MenuPopupHelper optionsMenu = new MenuPopupHelper(this, menuBuilder);
        optionsMenu.setForceShowIcon(true);
          menuBuilder.setCallback(new MenuBuilder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder menu, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.one:
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuModeChange(MenuBuilder menu) {

            }
        });
        optionsMenu.show();
}
```

In my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
        android:title="One"
        android:orderInCategory="0"/>
</menu>
```

calling it

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.option) {
            createMenu();
        }
}
```

getting error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor`

Comment: Share your XML please. (tag me when you do)

Comment: @FlyingNades done

Comment: Tested and crashing...

Comment: @ArghadipDasCEO do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to menu file `android:showAsAction="always"`

Use this menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_one"
    android:title="One"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0"/>
```

The issue is the null action view. So showing the menuitem as action view solves the issue

And call this using this code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.option) {
        createMenu(item.getActionView());
    }
```

}

And change your `createMenu()` to

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
public void createMenu(View v) {
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.show();

}
```

Comment: it's not `android:showAsAction="always"` it's `app:showAsAction="always"` btw let me try

Comment: You are using icon in popup menu, there are no by default implementation on popup menu with icon. Either you remove icon or force the use of icon by overriding the constructor.

Comment: Remove android:icon="@drawable/ic_one" it will work fine.

Comment: tried that still saying `MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor`

Comment: Where and how are you calling createMenu() Make an edit for clarification

Comment: I'm calling it `onOptionsItemClick`

Comment: I think i got what is your problem just edit your ques and add onOptionsItemClick code and then i will edit my answer

Comment: Bad answer you changed my code, I need it with icons